# How to use Scrapy in Anaconda?

Tags: python, scrapy, anaconda

I am very new to programming and may have asked a very silly question. Kindly bear with me.

I have installed Anaconda, and I have installed Scrapy as a package. In Anaconda Navigator > Environments > roots, Scrapy can be found as a package.

Now I start to follow the Scrapy tutorial ([Link](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html)) and come across the following instruction:

[image: Creating a project]

May I know, where in the Anaconda Natvigator should I click so that I have a "compiler" writing screen for me to enter the code?

Thanks!

Comment: Compiler writing screen? :) it's called a command line, or terminal prompt

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should open  " Anaconda Prompt " ----------a terminal using Linux Command line in your Anaconda directory：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhxje.png)

then, type **scrapy startproject yourproject_name** ,it will create a project in current directory.
after you finish your scrapy_project, type : **scrapy crawl the_name_in_your_class_of_yourcode** , it will show the INFO and result !!!

Answer (score 1):

I used the Anaconda prompt, put the scrapy instructions there like this:

[image: image anaconda prompt]

Comment: anaconda prompt in windows you find it on menu start, locate your anaconda3

Answer (score 0):

Create an environment via your terminal. ON windows, this is the command prompt. You can look up the https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html Once you have that use pip or conda to install scrapy to that environment, and then run the scrapy script in a directory of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

The Anaconda Navigator itself does not execute Python code. Open some Python IDE within the Navigator. I suggest Spyder. From Spyder, use the IPython window and type the command.